# How to Create a custom opencv buildpack for heroku

Tags: opencv, heroku, buildpack

Yes, I am aware of the fact that there are many compiled libraries available but currently, none of them are working properly. Also, the lack of proper guides which chalk out the steps for creating OpenCV buildpacks(or any buildpack for that fact of matter but more specifically opencv's buildpack) have lead me to post this question here. How to create custom a opencv buildpack? **I want to make the compiled library from scratch and host it.**

Again, emphasizing on the fact that **I DON'T want to use the existing ones due to the problems in each of them**. It would be awesome if someone could post a link to some guide or could give the steps to build one here itself. It would be very helpful for the poor souls who want to BUILD a custom buildpack on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a custom OpenCV buildpack using Docker. Then I deployed it on Heroku using [Heroku Container Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime).

Here is the GitHub link for the repository which I created containing the Dockerfile used to install OpenCV and other libraries: https://github.com/hulkinBrain/docker-opencv2

Also here is the Docker hub link for the same: https://hub.docker.com/r/hulkinbrain/docker-opencv2/